# What did Ginny get Harry for his birthday?

Tags: harry-potter

Ginny spends some time describing the present she got Harry for his 17th birthday.

> "I couldn't think what to get you," she said.
>   "You didn't have to get me anything."
>   She disregarded this too.
>   "I didn't know what would be useful. Nothing too big, because you wouldn't be able to take it with you."
>   [...]
>   "So then I thought, I'd like you to have something to remember me by, you know, if you meet some Veela when you're off doing whatever you're doing."
>   <sub>*(Deathly Hallows, Chapter 7, The Will of Albus Dumbledore)*.</sub>

Yet she doesn't actually say what she got him.

What was the small, useful and memorable gift she got him for his birthday? Or did she not find him anything?

Comment: Have you ever been a 17 year old boy? I fear this isn't a hp question but a biology one. However i do not advise googling this particular topic if you are underage, ask e.g. your parents instead. Her gift was what Harry wanted and useful for keeping the relationship alive.

Comment: @Raditz_35 On one level, sure, I see where you're coming from. But remember that they'd broken up only a few weeks earlier. So Harry wasn't expecting anything, neither was he looking to keep the relationship going.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

### Her gift was a (passionate) kiss.

> *"So then I thought, **I'd like you to have something to remember me by**, you know, if you meet some Veela when you're off doing whatever you're doing."*
>   *‘I think dating opportunities are going to be pretty thin on the ground, to be honest.’*
>   *‘There’s the silver lining I’ve been looking for,’ she whispered, **and
>   then she was kissing him as she had never kissed him before**, and Harry
>   was kissing her back, and it was blissful oblivion, better than
>   Firewhisky; she was the only real thing in the world, Ginny, the feel
>   of her, one hand at her back and one in her long, sweet-smelling hair
>   –*

Given that she was disappointed to be interrupted, it's also very possible that she intended to go further than just a kiss...

> *There was a strained silence, then Ginny said in a flat little voice,
>   ‘Well, happy birthday anyway, Harry.’*

But as JKR said, that's [not the sort of thing that you'd go into detail about in a fantasy book aimed at children](http://www.vulture.com/2012/09/jk-rowling-sex-new-yorker.html).

Comment: A kiss is neither compact nor useful. Also, she presumably gave him *lots* of kisses in the preceding weeks when they were dating.

Comment: @TheDarkLord - This was an especially passionate kiss.

Comment: @TheDarkLord - Also, she points out that this gift isn't useful, its "*something to remember [her] by*"

Comment: @TheDarkLord A kiss isn't compact or useful, but I don't think that's what Ginny was saying. She needed to get him a present, but there were lots of constraints. She couldn't get him something big and bulky. In the end, she couldn't find any object to give him, so she gave him the kiss instead. I mean I think the idea is, I couldn't think what to get you, it couldn't be something big for example. So in the end I decided to give you a kiss. Rather than, I couldn't get you somehting big, so I've got you this small compact thing

Comment: I've always read that bit as a "I want you to know how I feel before you go" with a slight "in case I never see you again" ring to it.

Comment: @JonClements Yeah, but I always thought that was in addition to an actual (material) gift. I saw the kiss as a spontaneous bonus from the moment, not a "Honey, I didn't get you a present this year but how about I give you a kiss?" substitute. But if this is the only answer then I may have to change my mind...

Comment: @TheDarkLord JKR herself has said that was the gift, if i remember right. But regarding "not compact or useful", well, a kiss itself takes no physical space (it's an idea/action), so i guess it could be considered compact. And never deny the power of morale. A kiss is EXTREMELY useful to morale.

Comment: @AytAyt If you could find that quote it would make a pretty good answer...

Comment: @TheDarkLord Yeah, that's why I made it a comment :P I have been looking for a bit, and can't find it, so the JKR part should be considered untrue for now.

Comment: Do you really expect the dark lord to understand anything related to love?

Comment: @Malcolm Indeed, it _is_ the "power he knows not".

Comment: I wonder whether this one was good enough to make [S. Morgenstern's top five list](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UUEdyXoMkgA).